# Am I using `all` correctly?

Tags: python

A user asked ([Keyerror while using pandas in PYTHON 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758495/keyerror-while-using-pandas-in-python-2-7)) why he was having a `KeyError` while looking in a dictionary and how he could avoid this exception.

As an answer, I suggested him to check for the keys in the dictionary before. So, if he needed all the keys `['key_a', 'key_b', 'key_c']` in the `dictionary`, he could test it with:

```
if not all([x in dictionary for x in ['key_a', 'key_b', 'key_c']]):
    continue
```

This way he could ignore dictionaries that didn't have the expected keys (the list of dictionaries is created out of JSON formatted lines loaded from a file). **Refer to the original question for more details, if relevant to this question.*

A user more experienced in Python and SO, which I would consider an authority on the matter for its career and gold badges told me I was using `all` incorrectly. I was wondering if this is really the case (for what I can tell, that works as expected) and why, or if there is a better way to check if a couple of keys are all in a dictionary.

Comment: Just as an aside to your question here, but if you are concerned about whether a key is in a dictionary before trying to get it's value you can always call the `get()` method on the dict.  So `dict.get('key', None)` will return either the value of `key` or `None`, where as `dict['key']` could result in a KeyError.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes that will work fine, but you don't even need the list comprehension

```
if not all(x in dictionary for x in ['key_a', 'key_b', 'key_c']):
    continue
```

If you have the surrounding `[]`, it will evaluate all the elements before calling `all`. If you remove them, the inner expression is a generator, and will [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) upon the first `False`.

Comment: `should_we = lambda: False  # e.g. NO` and `destroy_world = lambda: "Call forth Cthulhu, eater of worlds"`, then `if all(f() for f in (should_we, destroy_world)): print("are we still here?")` will not destroy the world.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The problem with that is that Cthulhu can travel in time, as well as in generator expression order, so he may be called first unfortunately :P

Comment: @CoryKramer: yet *until* he has been called forth, he'll just have to remain dormant. A dormant Cthulhu is a happy and *stationary* Cthulhu, in both time and space. :-)

Comment: I thought you called Cthulhu _fourth_, not first.